# PFGeoPoint not working on xcode7-ios9

Tags: swift, geopoints

I am trying to retrieve the current user location with Parse. But for some reason beyond my knowledge I am not being able to get anything to happen inside the block bellow. Neither point nor error.

I am running xcode 7 with ios9.

```
   func geoLocation(){
        print("GEO LOCATION")
        PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (point: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            print("POINT\(point)\(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the function `geoLocation` even being called? That is, does the _first_ `print` ever happen?

Comment: Also, do you have the necessary permission? Parse can't learn the device's location unless the user has explicitly given your app permission to use location services.

Comment: Yes the function is called. Will parse get the location on simulator?

Comment: The simulator doesn't have a location unless you give it one with Debug > Location. In theory I suppose this should work; I don't know about Parse specifically. - Okay, so the function is called. But I don't know what Parse does if you haven't obtained the user's permission; have you?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

and

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Put this keys in the info.plist

This is now a requirement for IOS 8 and above.